# How to check on google sheet/ranges protection status?

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet-protection

I made a code with @OMila aid to restrict some ranges for certain users while protecting the whole remaining ranges in sheet from their editing.. I want to check on the protection status of a sheet/range per for loop iteration, if it is protected ==> iteration++ (check next sheet), if not protected, run the script and protect ranges. The purpose is, when certain people make new sheets, I want the script to run automatically via a trigger, but when the number of sheets increase the execution time will increase per spreadsheet and will probably hit google quotations limit, so i need to make an optimized way to execute the script by putting an if condition to check the sheet protection status and do as described before. this is the code:

```
  function Sheet_Ranges_Protection() {
  var Veranda_Test = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Sheet ID");
  var Veranda_Sheets = Veranda_Test.getSheets();

  for(var SheetNumb = 0; SheetNumb < Veranda_Sheets.length; SheetNumb++) {

    var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();

    // Define ranges that will be protected for everyone
    var range1 = Veranda_Sheets[SheetNumb].getRange(6, 1, 
    Veranda_Sheets[SheetNumb].getMaxRows(), 
    Veranda_Sheets[SheetNumb].getMaxColumns());
    var range2 = Veranda_Sheets[SheetNumb].getRange(1, 8, 5, 
    Veranda_Sheets[SheetNumb].getMaxColumns());
    var range3 = Veranda_Sheets[SheetNumb].getRange(1, 4, 5);
    var ranges = [range1, range2, range3];

    // Set protection for all the sheet minus QC/PLN ranges
    for(var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
      var rangeProtection = ranges[i].protect().setDescription('Range protection');
      rangeProtection.addEditor(me);
      rangeProtection.removeEditors(rangeProtection.getEditors());
      if (rangeProtection.canDomainEdit()) {
        rangeProtection.setDomainEdit(false);
      }
    }

    var QC_Range         = Veranda_Sheets[SheetNumb].getRange("E1:G5");
    var PLN_Range        = Veranda_Sheets[SheetNumb].getRange("A1:C5");

    // Set protection for QC range
    var QC_protection = QC_Range.protect().setDescription('QC protection');
    QC_protection.removeEditors(QC_protection.getEditors());
    QC_protection.addEditor('Editor1@gmail.com');
    if (QC_protection.canDomainEdit()) {
      QC_protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    }

    // Set protection for PLN range
    var PLN_protection = PLN_Range.protect().setDescription('PLN protection');
    PLN_protection.removeEditors(PLN_protection.getEditors());
    PLN_protection.addEditor('Editor2@gmail.com');
    if (PLN_protection.canDomainEdit()) {
      PLN_protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    }    
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `getProtections()` function to check which kinds of protections are already in place before creating new ones.

Since you are creating your protection with ranges exclusively, you could use `getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE)` to fetch only the protections created by your script (all of them are Ranges, not sheets-wide protections).

You could assume that, if you have created the first protection, you have created all of them. So the code would look like this:

```
var protections = Veranda_Sheets[SheetNumb].getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
if (protections.length==0) {
   //add protections here
}
```

If that's not a safe assumption, you could verify which protections are lacking, and create them later like this:

```
var protections = Veranda_Sheets[SheetNumb].getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
var protectionNames = [];
for (var i=0; i<protections.length; i++) {
    protectionNames.push(protections[i].getDescription());
}

if (!protectionNames.includes('<name of protection i am about to create>') {
    //create protection '<name of protection i am about to create>'
} //else skip;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: checking if any range is protected is an enough indication for me that the sheet is protected the way i want, hence i only need the code part to check on first/whatever range... how the code will be now?

Comment: @Samy I've updated the answer to address your comment. Hope it helps you! Remember to accept the answers that are useful to you!

Comment: DUDE!!! Thank you so much, man!! I am so grateful to your help! 5 stars <3
this helps minimize execution time a great deal, it's more optimized now, thank you so much for your help!